# angular resource is mistaken as C# MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I keep getting this error from ELMAH

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/bundles/angular-resource.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.

But the bundleConfig.cs

```
//angular framework
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
  "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
  "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"));
```

The ~/Scripts folder has angular-resource.min.js.map file.  Doesn't anyone know what is going on?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you change it to `~/bundles/angular` to `~/scripts/angular` and test it again?

Comment: It has been with the name "~bundles/angular" for years.  I never have this problem until I reinstall angularjs 1.5.8 version two days ago.

Comment: One way to get this exception is to create a real physical "bundles" directory.  (If it exists delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you will look down of your min files you will find

```
//# sourceMappingURL=
```

So when you load browser will try to load source map. Since your bandle path is **"~/bundles/angular"** browser will try to load against **bundles** url and not **scripts** folders.
What you can do instead of

```
"~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
"~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"
```

remove min

```
"~/Scripts/angular.js",
"~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"
```

Bundler should minify your scripts from original sources

Lastly for me its a bit strange why you use bundle to minify minified files, as an option you can also just include scripts using

```
 <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah, I didn't realize bundle does minification on the way.  Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add that this also applies to the use of the `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/foo.min.js")` razor code, so if you change the file from the `foo.min.js` to the regular `foo.js` file, the above solution applies.