# AngularJS Bundle Config failing (angular-sanitize.js)

Tags: c#, angularjs

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/bundles/angular/angular-resource.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.

This error is thrown on every page load across my application.   Since I'm not bundling/minifying in Debug, this only occurs in QA/Dev and Production

I've tried this: [angular resource is mistaken as C# MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499000/angular-resource-is-mistaken-as-c-sharp-mvc-controller/40499135#40499135) (like adding the .min script tags to index.cshtml in-line, and the other suggestions)

An I've read this:  [MSDN: Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Here is the relevant code:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
#if (!DEBUG)
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        bundles.UseCdn = true;
#endif

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery/script")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"
                )
            );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular/script")
            .Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-modal.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-datepicker.js"
                )
            );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application/script")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true)
            );

        //Markup removed for clarity.
    }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery/script")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular/script")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/application/script")

//Markup removed for clarity.
```

**Directory Paths**

```
(Project.Web)/Scripts/angular-{whatever}.js
(Project.Web)/Scripts/angular-{whatever}.min.js
(Project.Web)/Scripts/angular-{whatever}.min.js.map
```

This include angular-sanitize, of course

I've also tried both removing and including

```
//# sourceMappingURL=angular-sanitize.min.js.map
```

from angular-sanitize.min.js

**If you need more information - please leave a comment! Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Changing the virtualPath parameter of the BundleCollection.Add() method solved this issue.

Changed this:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular/script")
        .Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-modal.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-datepicker.js"
            )
        );

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular/script")
```

To this:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/angular")
        .Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-modal.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-datepicker.js"
            )
        );

    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular")
```

If anyone understands the intricacies of BundleCollection, please let us know why this solution worked.

**EDIT**

If you JUST extract angular-sanitize, like so:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/angular")
        .Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"
            )
        );
```

Then the error becomes

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path
>   '/bundles/angular-resource.min.js.map' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.